# Count nested shortcodes, then reset for next parent shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Bit of an interesting question that's puzzling me, so I know how to count how many times a shortcode is called on a page using a static counter. However, I want to reset the counter whenever the parent shortcode is called:

```
<?php function gw_row($atts, $content = null) {
    return '<div class="gw-row">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>'; 
} add_shortcode("gw-row", "gw_row");

function gw_column($atts, $content = null) {
    static $count = 0; $count++; if($count > 5){$count = 0}
    return '<div class="column">'.do_shortcode( $content ).'</div>';
} add_shortcode("gw-column", "gw_column");?>
```

So explaining it further, there will be multiple `[gw-row]` shortcodes on a page, this is the 'Parent Shortcode'. Within this shortcode I use `[gw-column]`. I want to count how many columns are used on the page within each parent shortcode.

**Example:**

```
[gw-row]
    [gw-column]$Count = 1[/gw-column]
    [gw-column]$Count = 2[/gw-column]
[/gw-row]
               Reset $count
[gw-row]
    [gw-column]$Count = 1[/gw-column]
    [gw-column]$Count = 2[/gw-column]
    [gw-column]$Count = 3[/gw-column]
[/gw-row]
               Reset $count
```

I've thought about making `[gw-row]` an object and resetting `$count` just after the closing of the `<div>` which might work, but I wonder if there's a better way?

**My thoughts:**

```
<?php function gw_row($atts, $content = null) {
    global $count;
    ob_start();?>
        <div class="gw-row">
            <?php do_shortcode($content);?>
        </div><?php $count = 0;?>
    <?php return ob_clean();
} add_shortcode("gw-row", "gw_row");

function gw_column($atts, $content = null) {
    $count++; if($count > 5){$count = 0}
    return '<div class="column">'.do_shortcode( $content ).'</div>';
} add_shortcode("gw-column", "gw_column");?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I was seriously overthinking this, the solution is quite simple and close to what I suggested.

Simply define `$count` globally and set it to 0 in the `[gw-row]` shortcode. This will reset it every time it's called:

```
<?php function gw_row($atts, $content = null) {
    global $count; $count = 0;
    return '<div class="gw-row">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>'; 
} add_shortcode("gw-row", "gw_row");

function gw_column($atts, $content = null) {
    global $count; $count++; if($count > 5){$count = 0}
    return '<div class="column">'.do_shortcode( $content ).'</div>';
} add_shortcode("gw-column", "gw_column");?>
```